# Excel multiple values to SUM

Tags: excel

I have a little range that has a list of different teams.

```
1 Team1    20
2 Team2     5
3 Team3     7
4 Team4     6
5 Everyone (Sum of numbers above)
```

I am currently using a vlookup to pick how many team members to calculate for. I need to be able to put 1,3 and calculate for 27 or 2,4 and calculate for 11.

Of course I would also hope to use the same lookup for concatenating the labels as well 1, 3 Team1 Team 3 etc.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Could you extend the data sample results to show how you would use with Team name? 1, 3 Team1 Team 3  is not clear to me how that would work. Is that two teams and 1,3 from both? 1 from Team1 and 3 from Team3? Will Team1 and Team3 be comma separated as well? Will they be entered as a string in a cell as "1, 3 Team1 Team 3".... you see where I am going with this.

Answer (score 2):

## Interactive version using tables

You may not need a `vlookup` if you just want to be able to calculate the sums. If you place your data in a Table by adding headers and doing (Insert | Table), you can get an automatically updating total column with interactive filtering.

[image: Table with automatic updating total row]

## Using sumproduct

It may also be possible to handle this using SUMPRODUCT as shown below

[image: SUMPRODUCT version]

If you really want to enter a comma-separated list for the teams, you can build that participating column yourself:

[image: SUMPRODUCT with comma-separated list]

Comment: Cool I didn't know about this feature but It does not work in my application. I Have 30 rows that I will be calculating costs based on different participation of the teams. So my hope was to have a cell that i can indicate what teams will be participating in this activity and then calculate on that value.

Comment: @RogerK Perhaps you could extend your problem statement to include a little more detail? My first instinct is to use an extra column and `SUMPRODUCT` instead of entering the teams as comma separated lists.

Comment: @RogerK I have now added a full solution that starts with a comma-separated list as you asked for originally.

Comment: Note, it may be easier to use (more beginner friendly) [`=SUMIF()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) for this purpose, otherwise I like the answer

Comment: THanks I have been busy and have not been able to get back to working on this. I think the sum product will work. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, @RogerK since you are a new user, you might want to read the Stack Overflow help article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)